# overflow in javascript arithmetic

Tags: javascript, math, absolute-value

i was reading a book , and encountered this

> Arithmetic in JavaScript does not raise errors in cases of overflow,
> underflow, or division by zero. When the result of a numeric operation
> is larger than the largest representable number (overflow), the result
> is a special infinity value, Infinity. Similarly, when the absolute
> value of a negative value becomes larger than the absolute value of
> the largest representable negative number, the result is negative
> infinity, - Infinity.

how is it possible that the *result* of a *absolute value* of a *negative number* result in a *negative number*

Answer (score 1):

That's not what it says. if `|x| > |largest representable negative number| => -infinity` so if -10 is the largest representable negative number and x is 11 then the result is `-infinity`

Comment: is there a rational reason behind this

Comment: I also noticed that >>Math.pow(-3,99)    //-1.7179250691067045e+47 .
so -3 to the power of 99  resulted in  a negative representable number (which should be turned to the absolute value of it when using Math.abs() , and that indeed what happens
i.e..,  >>Math.abs(Math.pow(-3,99))      //1.7179250691067045e+47
, but >>Math.pow(-3,999)    //-Infinity , so here -3 to the power of 999 is an overflow/bypassed the largest representable number whoever that is , 
so when i get the absolute value of this one it should result in -infinity , but it doesn't 
>>Math.abs(Math.pow(-3,999)) //Infinity

Comment: @polendina an absolute number will never be negative. `Math.abs(-infinity) === infinity`

Comment: @polendina to me it seems rather rational that if an overflow is represented with infinity then an underflow would be -infinity

Comment: `an absolute number will never be negative`  that's the cause of my confusion , as you explained that the author meant `if |x| > |largest representable negative number| => -infinity`